# Google Script calling html.index file to send email but not interpreting the HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Setting up a script to send a certain HTML email to specified recipients.

```
function EasyEmail() {
for (i = 1; i <=1; i++) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rangeemailaddress = sheet.getRange(i,1); 
var emailaddress = rangeemailaddress.getValue();

MailApp.sendEmail(emailaddress, "this is the email subject", doGet() );
}}

function doGet() {
return HtmlService
  .createTemplateFromFile('index')
  .evaluate().getContent.();
}
```

The code succesfully sends the email and references the file, however it reads it as text rather than HTML.

Any ideas?